# DataSnap migration from Delphi 7 to XE6

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe6, datasnap

Sorry again for my english,
I already migrating client and the server and everything worked well, 
until I noticed that Remote Data Module of the server is not working what is expected. When I run query from a client that requires more time, the other Remote Data Modules remain on hold (including and the main thred). It behaves like thread model is tmSingle. I looked around and tried everything I found with no success. Even more strange is that where I registered the new server (builded with XE6), the old one (builded with D7) started giving the same symptoms.

When installing the new server on machine that is alredy running the old one I use

xxxxx.exe /unregserver (for the old one) and

xxxxx.exe /regserver (for the new one), and then is noticeable the problem. Even if I unregister the new server, and register the old one the problem stays.

The client and the server communicate via DataSnap Socket (the client with TSocketConnection and TConnectionBroker).

Here is some info for the server

Server_TLB

```
unit Server_TLB;
uses Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Graphics, Midas, StdVCL, Variants;
const

  LIBID_Server: TGUID = '{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}';

  IID_IrdmServer: TGUID = '{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}';
  CLASS_rdmServer: TGUID = '{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}';

  IrdmServer = interface;
  IrdmServerDisp = dispinterface;

  rdmServer = IrdmServer;

  IrdmServer = interface(IAppServer)
    ['{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}']
    ........... methods..........


  IrdmServerDisp = dispinterface
    ['{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}']
    ........... methods..........

  CordmServer = class
    class function Create: IrdmServer;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IrdmServer;

implementation

uses ComObj;

class function CordmServer.Create: IrdmServer;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_rdmServer) as IrdmServer;
end;

class function CordmServer.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IrdmServer;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_rdmServer) as IrdmServer;
end;

end.
```

..initialisation of the RDM

```
initialization
  TComponentFactory.Create(ComServer, TrdmServer,
    Class_rdmServer, ciMultiInstance, tmFree);
```

..the sequence of creation

```
    Forms.Application.ShowMainForm := False;
    Forms.Application.Initialize;
    Forms.Application.CreateForm(TdmServer, dmServer);
    Forms.Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
    windows.PostMessage(fMain.Handle, MSG_INITIALIZE, 0, 0);
    Forms.Application.Run;
```

with standard SocketDispatcher and standart SConnect

Also alredy tryed with setting key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}\InprocServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Free" or "Both"
```

I miss something else?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I would create a simple DataSnap client / server application with the correct threading model, test it, and then compare the auto-generated server module code with the code in your migrated project.

This way, you can detect the critical differences, adjust the code to be the equivalent in the test project server module.

Comment: I already test with new simple created DataSnap server/client and seems to work fine. But the architecture of the D7 and XE6 servers are different. I thing there cannot be compared. Will see again tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check:

Security on a Midas / DataSnap server: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=8814

Also, the socket server is deprecated and has some drawbacks:

- It bypasses DCOM security. Everything is run in the security context of the user which runs the server (if it is localsystem, it has the most powerful privileges - beware of that)
- Connection is not encrypted unless you write a module for it, which lacks basic securee key exchange features. DCOM can encrypt and authenticate packets (although its encryption is today not really strong) - you just need to configure it in dcomcnfg.
- It doesn't support 64 bit values and other types, see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=69924

Comment: I have already applied the fixes in UpdateRegistry in the project. The issue is not there. 10x

Comment: Did you check if client and server on the same machine work using DCOM directly?

Comment: Also, event viewer reports nothing? I would also suggest using a debugging facility (remote debugging, sysinternals debugview/ProcessMonitor, etc.) to track what the server actually does and where it hangs.
Check dcomcnfg settings also. Delphi DCOM Datasnap dìdn't really changes since at least D5-D6, but Windows did. What OS are you running on?

Comment: No event records in the event viewer, in debug - calling method from first client hits the breakpoint, in this time calling another metod from second client - goes inside the second method when the first one finishes. In DCOMConfig I do not find anithing useful. Thanks

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).